# Actual version of Webpack - ValidationError: Style Loader Invalid Options options should NOT have additional properties

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, sass

In order not to tell a lot of unnecessary information, I will be brief. The code below works fine. When I change `'style-loader'`  to a seemingly equivalent code(they are equal by default) `{ loader: 'style-loader', options: { injectType: 'styleTag' }}` I get this error - **ValidationError: Style Loader Invalid Options options should NOT have additional properties**

```
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    // Exclude files from these locations
    exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
    include: [__dirname + "/src", defaultThemePaths.src],
    // fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      // Default style loader
      'style-loader',

      //reason we don't watch scss and css at the same time sass-loader see https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2251
      //SASS loader

      // CSS loader
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        // Scepcify options for the CSS loader
        options: {
          // Root - must be specified in order to resolve URLs
          // in css files and pick up on any images and fonts.
          //root: paths.appSrc,
          importLoaders: 2,
          localIdentName: "[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:3]",
          modules: true
        }
      },
      {
        loader: "sass-loader",
        options: {
          data: '@import "./src/styles/core";'
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

As a result, I need to change `injectType: 'styleTag'` that is the default value of `'style-loader'` line to `injectType: 'linkTag'`